# Email Attachment controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, controller, attachment

Apologies in advance for the quality of my code :-)I am not a developer so my skill is limited. I am trying to render a VF page on our case console app which would display all attachments for all emails associated to a case. I thought that I would be able to take an example and tweak it but seems no one else is doing this so I tried from scratch. I need to somehow get the case Id in the controller I tried using the standard controller but not sure if that is correct approach.

**Controller:-**

```
Public Class AttachmentController
 {

    public AttachmentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

        Public List<Attachment> GetAttachments(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
        {
          string casId = controller.getRecord().Id;
          List<Attachment> attachedFiles = [SELECT Name, Body, ContentType, parentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage WHERE ParentId =:casId)];
          if( attachedFiles != null)
           {
             return attachedFiles;
           }
        return attachedFiles;
        }

  }
```

**VF:-**

```
<apex:page Controller="AttachmentController">


<apex:repeat var="att" value="{!attachedFiles}">

    <apex:outputLink value="/{!att.Id}" target="_blank">View File</apex:outputLink>
</apex:repeat>


</apex:page>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

You need a [controller extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm). With this, you'll be able to get the current case by using the standard controller parameter in the extension's constructor.

Also, if you want to share a variable between a Visualforce page and a controller, you need a property with a getter and setter or a public method with the name: "Get" + "PropertyName".

Finally, you're not requesting the `Id` field of the attachments but you're displaying it in the VF Page.

Here's the right code for what you need:

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extension="AttachmentController">


<apex:repeat var="att" value="{!attachedFiles}">

    <apex:outputLink value="/{!att.Id}" target="_blank">View File</apex:outputLink>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
Public Class AttachmentController
 {
    public List<Attachment> AttachedFiles {get; set;} //this is a way to share data between the controller and the page

    public AttachmentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { //this is where you can get the current case
       this.AttachedFiles = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage WHERE ParentId =:controller.getId()];
    }
  }
```